# The 'attribution-reporting' feature policy must be enabled to register a conversion

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm running into an error that's conflicting with my chrome extension development.

The error in my console says:
The 'attribution-reporting' feature policy must be enabled to register a conversion.

For some background, it's only showing up on this one particular Google chrome browser.

If I try another Google profile on the same machine, my extension works fine. It even works with my same profile on another machine. This attribution reporting error seems to be isolated to this one browser, on this one machine, and for this one Google profile.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

I've tried to reset my cache and cookies for the browser and also reset permissions.

Thank you!